# highest Z-index but can't click image href

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm creating this website:
https://www.melkerhei.be/smeltkroes/index.html

The logo in the left upper corner should be clickable. 
This is the code:

```
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo_box_top" style="z-index:20">
                 <a href="index.html" style="z-index:20">
                          <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Smeltkroes">
                  </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Perhaps the nav bar in the middle is in the way. I tried alot by changing positions and z-index'es of the elements but nothing works. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: does the z-index use meets the requirement ? -*The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.*- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: remove pointer-events: none; from the header class

Comment: When inspecting your site I find that I'm clicking on

`<div class="row justify-content-center">`
instead of clicking on the logo. Review other parts of your site overlaying this image.

The snippet above seems to be working fine on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pointer-events: none` on the `.header` class, all children will also have pointer events disabled by default.

The documentation for `pointer-events: none;` states:

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

You could leave this if you have a specific reason and set an explicit pointer event value on the children if you want them to be clickable. You probably don't need it though and can just remove it.

[image]

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

### **EDIT**

Based on your commments, here is your solution:

- Leave the `pointer-events: none;` on the `.header` class.
- Add `pointer-events: all;` to the anchor element within the header.

Then you can still click the header link without effecting your other layers.

Comment: When I remove the pointer-events my artists (images in body) aren't clickable anymore. Because they have a smaller z-index than the header (because the edge-images needs to be on the foreground)..

Answer (score 0):

Z-index can't do anything because there is no position, Z-index always works with positions for exmaple:

```
logo_box_top { 
  z-index: 20;
  position: static;
}
```

You can use relative, absolute and etc